# IMAP losing 'X-Header' from exchange server

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2007

I have Exchange 2007 installed on Windows 2003 Server. I am having difficulties with the additional 'X-headers' being removed when my messages are delivered to my inbox via IMAP.

For example, when I receive emails with very specific X-Headers that are needed to be kept in tact they disappear when the message finally arrives at the inbox using IMAP.

However, When I log onto OWA I can see the headers no problem, however when I set up any mail-client to retrieve my messages via IMAP the specific X-Headers are lost.

At present I am using Thunderbird, but this is the same with both Outlook and Thunderbird.

Is there something that can be done to keep the full headers in tact without adjusting the original headers in anyway?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is bigger than just `IMAP`. `POP3` also doesn't have the `X-Headers`. 
I believe the issue has to do with Exchange not keeping the full Mime structure when it stores  emails and instead only returning promoted named properties.

You may have luck with changing the `HeaderPromotionModeSetting` to `MayCreate`. as refrenced in this [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stuartp/archive/2009/12/08/new-feature-in-exchange-server-2007-sp2-headerpromotionmodesettings.aspx). **Make sure that you note the potential nightmare in changing it back to the original behavior before implementing on production.**

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me: set-transportconfig -HeaderPromotionModeSetting MayCreate.
Perfect!

Comment: Well mark it as correctly answered then :)